# How to get list of databases in mongodb for which user is having access?

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication

Is it possible to get list of databases in Mongodb for which a particular user is having access?

Answer (score 1):

In the MongoDB shell, the following command will list the databases:

```
db.adminCommand('listDatabases')
```

or

```
db.getMongo().getDBNames()
```

For the current Java API, use the **[MongoClient](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html)**'s **[`listDatabaseNames()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#listDatabaseNames--)** method which returns an iterable containing all the names of all the databases. As an example (untested):

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class JavaMongoDBConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

            MongoIterable<String> allDatabases = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames();

            for (String dbName : allDatabases) {                

                DB db = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);

                char[] password = new char[] {'s', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't'};
                boolean authenticated = db.authenticate("user", password);

                if (authenticated) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully logged in to MongoDB!");
                    System.out.println("Database: " + dbName);

                    Set<String> collections = db.getCollectionNames();
                    for (String colName : collections) {
                        System.out.println("\t + Collection: " + colName);
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid username/password");
                }

            }

            mongoClient.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you are taking about client.listDatabaseNames(); rather than db.listDatabaseNames();. Are you sure will this work when mongod is launched with --auth option. For me its giving exception.

Comment: Using List<String> allDatabases = mongoClient.getDatabaseNames(); is giving error not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1 }.

Comment: So it looks like without authentication its not possible to list all databases.

Comment: @Alien01 Not sure where you are getting the `getDatabaseNames();` method from, as far as I know that's been deprecated with the current Java API. Have you tried `mongoClient.listDatabaseNames();`?

Comment: I was using old version of driver..now using latest version.But problem still persists..cannot get database names without authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can check the access of specific user by finding that user in 
**system.users** collection. their you can add projection on **db** key which comes under **roles** key.

Here is the structure of doc in **users** collection.

```
{
  _id: <system defined id>,
  user: "<name>",
  db: "<database>",
  credentials: { <authentication credentials> },
  roles: [
           { role: "<role name>", db: "<database>" },
           ...
         ],
  customData: <custom information>
 }
```

Comment: Is there any Java api to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since the 4.0.5 MongoDB there is an option in listDatabases that allows to [filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/#definition) only the authorized Databases:

> *authorizedDatabases* [boolean] [Optional]: A flag that determines which databases are returned based on the user privileges when access control is enabled.

It may be something like:

```
return mongoClient.getDatabase("admin").runCommand(
      new BasicDBObject("listDatabases",
            new BasicDBObject("authorizedDatabases", 1)
      )
);
```

Read the full documentation as there are some subtle differences between versions:

- MongoDB 4.0.5: Databases with the *find* privilege
- MongoDB 4.0.6+: Databases with privileges to see, even if restricted
  to specific collections